# Digital identity is equal to public key + private key?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, code-signing

I am reading about application code signing in iOS and I don't understand why both private and public key is together? What is the public key and certificate used for when you are signing the application with the private?

[image]

> Xcode uses your digital identity to sign your application during the
>   build process. This digital identity consists of a public-private key
>   pair and a certificate. The private key is used by cryptographic
>   functions to generate the signature. The certificate is issued by
>   Apple; it contains the public key and identifies you as the owner of
>   the key pair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Let's sum up the process:**

**You encrypt** an *hashed digest* (like md5 or sha-1) of the executable of application with your private key. That's "**signing**".

**Your users decrypt** it with your public key (they have it because it's public) and check it against the executable. As long as your private key stays private, it's you who "signed" it. That's called "**verifying**".

**What about the digital identity then:**

You public key isn't public by itself, it must be **somehow shared**, "made public", and signed by the Certification Autority (hereby CA) too, (that's the CA encrypting it —or an hash of it— with their, one of their, *magical mysterious private keys*) this guarantees the sharing process hasn't been tampered with by a man in the middle.

So, public key and certificate (CA signature — CA encrypting your public key) *identify you* (as such are considered part of your "digital identity") and must reach the end user somehow (via a third party, embedded into the executable, you name the way)

Answer (score 0):

The public key is needed so anyone can decrypt the application, and is hence included in the build.